# ResignFirstResponder from a function outside the view controller

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uipickerview, resignfirstresponder

I am currently working with `UITextField` with an inputview - `UIPickerView` and I have added a done button to the top the `UIPickerView`. I can close the picker view with the done button by resigning the first responder of the textfield from the view controller class using

```
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.dismissPickerView))

func dismissPickerView() {
    myTextField.resignFirstResponder
}
```

The problem is that I want to call a function out side the viewController class that resigns the first responder on the `myTextField` like below

```
func doneButton (viewcontroller: UIViewController,textfield:UITextField) {   
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(textfield.resignFirstResponder))
}
```

so I can use it for multiple picker views but I don't know how to implement the SELECTOR OF THE "`func doneButton`"

ANY FEEDBack will HELP

Answer (score 0):

You create a helper singleton class, which will be observing to UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification,UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification.
Store/Clear reference of text field or any other first-responder object when notification is fired

Add a static or object method to the singleton class which will be resigning first responder on the object previously stored from notification

**Swift 3.0**

```
class KeyBoardHelper {

var firstResponder:UIView?

static let sharedInstance = KeyBoardHelper()

static func initializedInstance()
{
    _ = sharedInstance
}

init()
{
    print("Start listning for keyboard event")

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(KeyBoardHelper.keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditing, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(KeyBoardHelper.keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UITextViewTextDidEndEditing, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification:Notification)
{
    firstResponder = notification.object as? UIView
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification:Notification)
{
    firstResponder = nil
}


static func resignKeyboard()
{
    KeyBoardHelper.sharedInstance.firstResponder?.resignFirstResponder()
}

@objc func dismissKeyboard()
{
    firstResponder?.resignFirstResponder()
}

static func resignBarButton() -> UIBarButtonItem
{
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.done, target: KeyBoardHelper.sharedInstance, action: #selector(KeyBoardHelper.dismissKeyboard))
    return barButton
}

}
```

Comment: I will try that now. and give my feedback. But I really don't get what you mean. because the doneButton function is a swift file without a class.

Comment: You can initialize a singleton at AppDelegate and pass singleton instance as target and selector as resign method of singleton while creating bar button